# Wordpress Fatal error: Allowed memory size exhausted

Tags: php, wordpress, memory, phpmyadmin

I'm in the process of importing a huge number of files via .CSV - all that seems to be going fine but after an import finished I started getting this error:

on the WordpPress post management page (`http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/edit.php`)

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 524288 bytes) in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-walker.php on line 176
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0016  857424  {main}( )   ..\edit.php:0
2   9.4654  31424712    WP_List_Table->display( )   ..\edit.php:249
3   9.4655  31425264    WP_List_Table->display_tablenav( )  ..\class-wp-list-table.php:709
4   9.4660  31425808    WP_Posts_List_Table->extra_tablenav( )  ..\class-wp-list-table.php:761
5   10.0549 31394480    wp_dropdown_categories( )   ..\class-wp-posts-list-table.php:222
6   16.4317 261790880   walk_category_dropdown_tree( )  ..\category-template.php:370
7   16.4441 266681480   call_user_func_array ( )    ..\category-template.php:763
8   16.4441 266682016   Walker->walk( ) ..\category-template.php:0
9   16.4441 266682064   func_get_args ( )   ..\class-wp-walker.php:176
```

and on the import CSV page (http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/tools.php?page=csv-importer/csv_importer.php) I get

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 63 bytes) in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-walker.php on line 176
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  707784  {main}( )   ..\tools.php:0
2   0.0014  827336  require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-admin\admin.php' )  ..\tools.php:10
3   0.2692  30508160    do_action( )    ..\admin.php:151
4   0.2692  30509656    call_user_func_array ( )    ..\plugin.php:405
5   0.2692  30509688    CSVImporterPlugin->form( )  ..\plugin.php:0
6   0.2694  30510936    wp_dropdown_categories( )   ..\csv_importer.php:111
7   6.3437  260920048   walk_category_dropdown_tree( )  ..\category-template.php:370
8   6.3582  265810672   call_user_func_array ( )    ..\category-template.php:763
9   6.3582  265811208   Walker->walk( ) ..\category-template.php:0
10  6.3582  265811256   func_get_args ( )   ..\class-wp-walker.php:176
```

I've been searching the last few days trying to figure this out - all fixes seem to point towards moding the php.ini with memory_limit (tried -1 and 9999m) or moding the WP config with define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M'); I echo'd out the php info to make sure changes where taking place and it seems they are. I'm running WAMP on windows 64x if that helps.

All posts show up fine on the frontend, it's just in the backend they seem to be producing this error. Honestly I've got no idea what to try next. Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: I think the first thing you should do is disable the csv import plugin to see if that fixes the problem on the posts list screen.  It doesn't look like it is from the stack trace, but who knows. If it isn't causing the problem then maybe you discovered a WP bug. How many posts do you currently have in the database?

Answer (score 1):

Some webservers may impose memory limits. Check your Apache settings to make sure its not the culprit.

Comment: I'm on my own machine - Windows 7 x64 running WAMP so should be quite flexible. Hmm... where would I find a memory setting in Apache? - Thanks

Comment: There may be a RLimMem directive in the httpd.config file.

Comment: Can't seem to find any mention of the rlimit or RLimitMEM in httpd.conf - would it be located anywhere else?

Comment: Looks like there might also be a memory line in the .htaccess file as well.

Comment: I also found reference to a possible registry key, 


        HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\Tomcat6\Parameters\Java\JmvMx .

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this bit of code at the top of `csv_importer.php`:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try these different settings in C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.6\bin\php.ini

    Find:
    post_max_size = 8M
    upload_max_filesize = 2M
    max_execution_time = 30
    max_input_time = 60
    memory_limit = 8M

    Change to:
    post_max_size = 750M
    upload_max_filesize = 750M
    max_execution_time = 5000
    max_input_time = 5000
    memory_limit = 1000M

    And add this to C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.0.45\my.ini:

    max_allowed_packet = 200M

    Then restart wamp
```